# Surface disappears in Matplotlib 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a sphere with a segment cut out.  I think I've created the co-ordinates correctly but I find that as I pan around the sliced sphere, the inner surface disappears.  What am I doing wrong?  If at all relevant, this is Python 2.7.3 with Matplotlib 1.5.1 on openSUSE Leap 42.1, using backend `TkAgg`.

[image: Everything correct.]
[image: After slight pan to the right.]

**Code**:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

phi = np.linspace(0.5*np.pi, 2.0*np.pi, 100)
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

x = np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta))
y = np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')

r = np.linspace(0.,1.,25)
x = np.outer(r, np.sin(theta))
y = 0.*x
z = np.outer(r, np.cos(theta))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, color='g')

ax.view_init(30.,60.)
pl.show()
```

Comment: This is a problem of the matplotlib 3d engine. It always has problems to decide which patches to display in front. Your 'inner surface' is then just hidden behind the sphere. You're doing nothing wrong here, it's just how matplotlib works or not-works. I do not know any good solution to such problems other than either selecting a viewing angle that suits you or maybe using a different plotting library like Mayavi.

Comment: With your inspiration, I've found that this is actually covered in the [FAQ](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html)... My fault for not searching for the right terms! Should I delete the question myself?

Comment: I'm not sure, you may leave it here to help others, having the same problem, to realize that there is no good solution to it.

Comment: Perhaps, to get the question closed, write a short answer quoting the most relevant part of that FAQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is such a common problem that it's mentioned in the [FAQ](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html):

> **My 3D plot doesn’t look right at certain viewing angles**
>
> This is probably the most commonly reported issue with mplot3d. The problem is that – from some viewing angles – a 3D object would appear in front of another object, even though it is physically behind it. This can result in plots that do not look “physically correct.”
>
> Unfortunately, while some work is being done to reduce the occurance of this artifact, it is currently an intractable problem, and can not be fully solved until matplotlib supports 3D graphics rendering at its core.

In this case, you can create a crude fix by plotting the three quarters of the sphere separately. e.g.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

# first quarter
phi = np.linspace(0.5*np.pi, 1.0*np.pi, 34)
x = np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta))
y = np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')

# second quarter
phi = np.linspace(1.0*np.pi, 1.5*np.pi, 34)
x = np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta))
y = np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')

# third quarter
phi = np.linspace(1.5*np.pi, 2.0*np.pi, 34)
x = np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta))
y = np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')

r = np.linspace(0.,1.,25)
x = np.outer(r, np.sin(theta))
y = 0.*x
z = np.outer(r, np.cos(theta))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, color='g')

ax.view_init(30.,60.)
pl.show()
```